# Why is my UI element invisible until the user resizes the window?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a custom progress bar–like view that basically consists of two sizers side by side: the one on the left has a red background and the one on the right has a light gray background. By adjusting the relative sizes of the sizers I can indicate different percentages. For whatever reason—maybe because this Window consists only of sizers, with no “substantial” elements—the progress bar is not visible when its containing Frame first appears. When the Frame is resized by any amount in any direction, the progress bar suddenly pops into view, with the correct size and position and everything.

Below is a minimal code sample. It doesn’t quite demonstrate the problem I’m describing: when run as-is, the progress bar will appear correctly.

If I remove the `wx.EXPAND` flag from either `Add()` call in `TestWindow.__init__`, however, then when the window first appears the progress bar will either be the wrong size or completely invisible. (Resizing the window causes the bar to become visible and/or take the correct size.) When the `run_on_main_thread` decorator is not applied to `update_sizes`, though, the bar is always displayed correctly right off the bat, regardless of whether the `wx.EXPAND` flag was included!

I’m not sure why my efforts toward thread safety have caused this drawing issue. Can anyone suggest a way to make the progress bar display correctly from the beginning, while still ensuring that `update_sizes` will only run on the main thread? For example, can I trigger an `EVT_SIZE` on the window so that it will refresh itself without any user interaction?

I’m using Python 2.7.5 and wxPython 2.9.5.0 on OS X 10.9.2.

### Code

```
from functools import wraps
from math import floor
import wx

def run_on_main_thread(fn):
    """Decorator. Forces the function to run on the main thread.

    Any calls to a function that is wrapped in this decorator will return
    immediately; the return value of such a function is not available.

    """
    @wraps(fn)
    def deferred_caller(*args, **kwargs):
        wx.CallAfter(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    
    return deferred_caller


class PercentageBar(wx.Window):
    def __init__(self, parent, percentage=0.0):
        wx.Window.__init__(self, parent)

        border_color = '#000000'
        active_color = '#cc0000'
        inactive_color = '#d3d7cf'
        height = 24

        self.percentage = percentage

        self.SetBackgroundColour(border_color)

        self.active_rectangle = wx.Panel(self, size=(-1, height))
        self.active_rectangle.SetBackgroundColour(active_color)

        self.inactive_rectangle = wx.Panel(self, size=(-1, height))
        self.inactive_rectangle.SetBackgroundColour(inactive_color)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.update_sizes()
    
    @run_on_main_thread
    def update_sizes(self):
        self.sizer.Clear(False)

        if self.percentage != 0.0 and self.percentage != 1.0:
            active_flags = wx.EXPAND | (wx.ALL & ~wx.RIGHT)
        else:
            active_flags = wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL

        self.sizer.Add(self.active_rectangle, floor(1000 * self.percentage),
                active_flags, 1)

        self.sizer.Add(self.inactive_rectangle, floor(1000 * (1.0 - self.percentage)),
                wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 1)

        if self.percentage == 0.0:
            self.active_rectangle.Hide()
            self.inactive_rectangle.Show()
        elif self.percentage == 1.0:
            self.active_rectangle.Show()
            self.inactive_rectangle.Hide()
        else:
            self.active_rectangle.Show()
            self.inactive_rectangle.Show()

        self.sizer.Layout()
        self.Refresh()


class TestWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title='Test')

        vertical_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vertical_sizer.Add((1, 1), 1)
        vertical_sizer.Add(PercentageBar(self, percentage=0.33), 2, wx.EXPAND)
        vertical_sizer.Add((1, 1), 1)

        horizontal_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        horizontal_sizer.Add((1, 1), 1)
        horizontal_sizer.Add(vertical_sizer, 10, wx.EXPAND)
        horizontal_sizer.Add((1, 1), 1)

        self.SetSizer(horizontal_sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    window = TestWindow(None)
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Can you provide a small runnable example and what OS you're on? Also, which version of Python and wxPython are you using?

Comment: @MikeDriscoll I’ve added some code.

Comment: I see a black bar in the middle of the frame when I run the code on Windows 7, wx 2.8.12 and Python 2.6. If you are using threads, make sure that any calls to wx elements are done via wx's thread-safe methods: wx.CallAfter and wx.PostEvent

Comment: @MikeDriscoll I’m using CallAfter. If you wouldn’t mind reading through my question again, I’ve edited it quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is working as expected for me with wxPython 3.0, but your symptom is a common one.  Usually it means that the initial size event is happening before the sizer has been set, so the default `EVT_SIZE` handler doesn't yet have a sizer to use for the layout.  As soon as the window is resized then the sizer is used to do the layout and all is as you expected it to be before.

To deal with this problem you just need to trigger the built-in layout features after the frame and its content have been created.  (Usually at the end of `__init__`)  Since the auto-layout is tied to the size events, then you can use the frame's `SendSizeEvent` method to let it have one.  Or you can just explicily call the `Layout` method yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn’t work either. Calling `SendSizeEvent` on the Frame and on the PercentageBar’s containing Window didn’t make it visible. I ended up using a “non-blocking lock” decorator instead of the “run on main thread” one and it seems to work okay.